# epsilon approximation of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading Theory of ordinary differential equastions by Earl A.coddington and Norman Levinson and I have a question about the $\epsilon$-approximate solution of an ODE in the book they say
[image]

and I can't understand why $M$ can't be $0$
I assume it cannot be $0$ because in the next line they say $\alpha = min\{a,\frac{b}{M}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the text does not seem to address whether $M=0$.

Jean-Claude Arbaut mentions in the comments that the problem may be trivial when $M=0$, because then $f$ vanishes everywhere.

Another possibility is that the authors adopt the "extended reals" convention, whereby $\frac{b}{0}=\infty$ for positive $b$.  Then $$\alpha=\min{\!\left(a,\frac{b}{0}\right)}=\min{\!\left(a,\infty\right)}=a$$

Only you can tell from context what the correct interpretation is.

Comment: From the context I think your interpretation is right. Here $\alpha$ is used to find a solution on the interval $[\tau,\tau+\alpha]$. A positive value of $M$ might reduce the length of this interval, but a zero $M$ is not going to be a problem, so in this case $\alpha=a$ seems sensible.